# Neo4J, getting all paths and shortest path

Tags: neo4j, nosql

I have 20 nodes and 21 paths that that are supposed to represent a labyrinth.

I now want to find all possible paths (there are 3) from start to finish.

I also want to find the path with the least amount of weight,in the case the least amount of damage.

Any help with the correct syntax and any tips for improvement is much appreciated,

This is querys that i have tried, not understood and failed at..

`MATCH p=(a {name:"START"})-[:PATH*tall woods..guard]->(s{name:"Finish"})
RETURN p AS shortestPath,
reduce(length=0, r in relationships(p) | length+r.length) AS totalLength
order by totalLength`

`MATCH p=(a {name:"START"})-[:ROAD*tall woods..guard]->(s{name:"Finish"})
RETURN p AS shortestPath,
reduce(length=0, r in relationships(p) | length+r.length) AS totalLength
order by totalLength
limit 1`

I assume [:Path*tall woods..guard] is wrong, should i write all paths seperated by comma or something else?

This is my labyrinth:

```
create(a:LABYRINTH {name:"START"})-[:PATH {name:"spiders", damage:1}]-> (b:LABYRINTH{name:"B"}),
(a)-[:PATH {name:"tall woods", damage:1}]->(c:LABYRINTH {name:"C"}),
(c)-[:PATH {name:"lizards", damage:1}]->(d:LABYRINTH {name:"D"}),
(c)-[:PATH {name:"gremlins", damage:3}]-> (e:LABYRINTH {name:"E"}),
(e)-[:PATH {name:"dark woods", damage:0}]->(f:LABYRINTH {name:"F"}),
(e)-[:PATH {name:"old bridge", damage:2}]->(g:LABYRINTH {name:"G"}),
(g)-[:PATH {name:"orc", damage:5}]->(i:LABYRINTH {name:"I"}),
(i)-[:PATH {name:"dead end", damage:0}]->(h: LABYRINTH {name:"H"}),
(i)-[:PATH {name:"dusty planes", damage:0}]->(j: LABYRINTH {name:"J"}),
(i)-[:PATH {name:"ape", damage:3}]->(k: LABYRINTH {name:"K"}),
(k)-[:PATH {name:"mob", damage:1}]->(q: LABYRINTH {name:"Q"}),
(g)-[:PATH {name:"woods", damage:0}]->(z: LABYRINTH {name:"Z"}),
(z)-[:PATH {name:"dead planes", damage:0}]->(k),
(z)-[:PATH {name:"desert", damage:1}]->(m: LABYRINTH {name:"M"}),
(m)-[:PATH {name:"gorilla", damage:0}]->(n: LABYRINTH {name:"N"}),
(m)-[:PATH {name:"bridge", damage:0}]->(l: LABYRINTH {name:"L"}),
(l)-[:PATH {name:"mud", damage:1}]->(o: LABYRINTH {name:"O"}),
(i)-[:PATH {name:"waters", damage:2}]->(r: LABYRINTH {name:"R"}),
(r)-[:PATH {name:"witch", damage:1}]->(p: LABYRINTH {name:"P"}),
(q)-[:PATH {name:"guard", damage:0}]->(s: LABYRINTH {name:"Finish"}),
(r)-[:PATH {name:"old witch", damage:1}]->(s)
```

Comment: Please post at least a query you have tried

Comment: All you've shown is your `CREATE`. Please edit your question accordingly to show what queries you've tried, results, and specific issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using [variable length relationships](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/match/#_variable_length_relationships), you need to use integers to specify the minimum and maximum number of relationship traversals (these are optional), you cannot supply values of properties here.

I highly encourage you to read through the developers guide, especially when you run into a wall trying to get something to work. A quick check on variable relationships would have easily revealed the correct means of using this functionality.

To find all possible paths, you'll want to match on your start and finish nodes, then use a match using a variable relationship between them:

```
MATCH (a:LABYRINTH {name:"START"}), (s:LABYRINTH {name:"Finish"})
MATCH p = (a)-[:PATH*]->(s)
RETURN p
```

As far as shortest paths of least weight, it's easiest to use the [dijkstra function](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_graph_algorithms_work_in_progress) after installing [APOC Procedures](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/). You will need to supply the start and end nodes, a filter of relationship types and direction to traverse, and the relationship property to use for weight.

```
MATCH (start:LABYRINTH{name:'START'}), (end:LABYRINTH{name:'Finish'})
CALL apoc.algo.dijkstra(start, end, 'PATH>', 'damage') YIELD path, weight
RETURN path, weight
```

EDIT

Responding to how to do this without APOC Procedures (though it is recommended, installation is about as easy as it comes, and you get quite a bit of useful functionality), you can do this, but you'll need to craft the evaluation of the weight yourself.

You'll do this by using the reduce() function, which you can use on the collection of relationships in your path to get the sum of the damage, then sort based upon that sum and get the path with the least damage.

```
MATCH p=(:LABYRINTH {name:"START"})-[rels:PATH*]->(:LABYRINTH {name:"Finish"})
WITH p, REDUCE(weight=0, rel in rels | weight + rel.damage) as damage
RETURN p, damage 
ORDER BY damage ASC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Shortest paths of least weights, Is there any other way of doing it without installing APOC Procedures?

Comment: Added an alternative to APOC procedures that should work for you.